# How to Save and Restoring gnome-terminal profiles for Ubuntu 20 LTS

Tags: gnome-terminal

The ways of saving and restoring gnome-terminal profiles seems to change with each major release of Ubuntu.
I have attempted all of the solutions listed going back to Ubuntu 16 with no luck in finding where
the profiles are stored and how to manipulate (edit) the profiles.
Please DO NOT refer me back to a solution for a prior version of Ubuntu and just give a straight forward answer.

Comment: "*The ways of saving and restoring gnome-terminal profiles*" changes whenever Gnome upstream changes them.

Comment: Please flag Answers that no longer work in any supported release of Ubuntu. If an Answer works in a previous release of Ubuntu, but not in 20.04, please leave a helpful comment (or suggest an edit) so others are not misdirected.